# How to unit-test a bootloader on PIC18 with TCP/IP stack used?

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded, tcp, pic18

I am developing a bootloader using the **XC8 C** compiler **1.12** in **MPLAB X 1.60** from Microchip. The target chip is **PIC18F87J60**.
My bootloader does some extra things bootloaders normally don't do. It downloads the app image to flash from a server and verifies its integrity by calculating the **MD5** hashsum. Also, it has to pass an authentication test at the server specific to this project.
For all of this to work, I use the TCP/IP stack **v5.42** from Microchip.

What I want to do now is thoroughly test the bootloader but I have some trouble selecting the right method and tools. I have access to a **Pickit 3 ICD** but not any other specialized hardware like logic analyzers etc. (except for an *ossciloscope*). The bootloader is implemented as a hierarchical **FSM** which may (or may not) complicate things even more.

I was thinking about at least unit test/module test all the different parts of the bootloader and considering all the states of the FSM's as separate functions. There are some unit test frameworks on the internet, some of which claim to be usable in embedded and restricted environments like mine.

The problem with those is that most are implemented as some sort of a C library to be compiled with the rest of the program but they all expect the compiler to follow some standard. The **XC8** compiler actually does follow the **C90** standard but not to its full extend (evidently by the 'Divergence from the ANSI C Standard' chapter in the docs). This is causing trouble in compiling the frameworks.

I might work around this problem by mocking up all of the hardware and register access's and test on my Windows 7 development machine but that would be a ton of work since I use the TCP/IP library which the bootloader heavily depends upon. Another downside is that ultimately I want to test on chip because C code may behave differently on the PIC chip than on my **intel i7**.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to properly `unit-/moduletest` my bootloader? Is it even a good idea to unit test such a program on such a platform? Are there any other test methodologies I might use?

Requirements/pre's/notes:

- I'm talking about whitebox testing methods. Blackbox testing isn't being painful at the moment. Besides, functionally the bootloader isn't compilated and all functional requirements are measurable.
- I want to automate the tests as much as possible and even automatically trigger testing when I press 'compile'.
- There aren't any strict performance requirements and I have some spare ROM memory so code instrumentation like putting in a lot of probes shouldn't be to big of a problem.
- I'm far from being a testing guru. Any fancy words I used above is from just a couple of hours of research but I don't have any actual testing experience.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts and suggestions.

Bitjunky,

Answer (score 2):

I have found unit testing in embedded systems to be very difficult. The side-effects from peripherals are extremely onerous. The most difficult to deal with are side effects triggered by reading a memory location (e.g. a read clearing a flag). The best thing you can do is isolate hardware access. Even within a module limiting access is a good idea. Unit testing is worthwhile but can can reach a point of diminishing returns much faster in embedded space than others.

I have had good luck with [seatest](https://code.google.com/p/seatest/). It is extremely basic; it does not offer the fancier features offered by [Unity](http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/unity-intro.html) et al (no automatic mock) but it is portable, straight C, and supports the core features needed for testing.

My second recommendation is to create a file with variables named after all the available registers your MCU has. It is easy to scrape Microchip's linker script for register names and stick them in a c file. This makes it much easier to get all of your code compiling on a PC platform. This can get you up and running faster and also makes testing easier.

Comment: I downloaded and tried seatest. It compiled after some tweaks but the PIC resets because of a stack overflow when doing an assert. I fear that any framework, no matter how small, is to big/complex for my 8-bit PIC18. I'll try building my own framework using [MinUnit](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's a fork of [Unity](http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/unity-intro.html) for Microchip's XC8 / PIC16, that does not use setjmp/longjmp, here: https://github.com/jwalkerbg/Unity

Using unit tests means your code should be *testable*. Organizing your code to this requirement may help you getting responsibilities and pre/post conditions for each function better defined.

Try to isolate the code that does not depend on hardware state (like md5 calculation) so you can test it on your development environment (running in your intel i7). Testing of this code may easily be automated (you may add a testing job to your building script, and you may also run everything in a continuous integration server).

For the code that depends on hardware state, you may *(1)* mock the hardware or use a simulator (and still run it in your development or continuous integration server environment), or *(2)* run the tests embedding it in your actual harware. Option *2* may not be easily automated. You may even have to deploy and run each test manually. Also, getting the test results may not me straightforward, since a console or file system may not be available in your embedded environment.